# c++ debugging return 0 back to variable

Tags: c++, debugging

I am new to C++ and I've been learning how a program is executed. I am working on this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void sayHello() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}

void greet(string name) {
    cout << "Hello " << name << ", how are you?" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    sayHello();
    int a = 10;
    string name = "Johan";
    greet(name);
    return 0;
}
```

I debugged this code in Code Blocks IDE. When it reached the `return 0` statement, the yellow arrow (step into mode) returned to the `string name` statement and then it went to the return statement again to finish the debugging. I thought it is related to freeing memory, but why didn't it go to the `int a = 10`?

Is it normal? What did the debugger do? Shouldn't the debugger go to the closing bracket directly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `std::string` is a class with a non-default destructor, and this is your debugger's way of telling you that it's about to destroy this `std::string` object, by invoking its destructor. The debugger is saying, in so many words "ok, I'm doing the return statement now, and the first order of business is to destroy this `std::string`, so the execution jumps to the line which declared this `std::string` object, to let you know I'm about to execute this destructor; now, there, I've done it, now I'll resume the process of returning from this function".

A plain `int` doesn't have a fancy-shmancy destructor, and nothing special needs to be done, in order to make it go away.